# How to remove duplicate python installation

Tags: python, path

Yesterday while using Python I noticed that a large number of packages I otherwise used were missing, like `matplotlib`. At the same time, some other program that I use that call to Python and `matplotlib`, were working fine. After some digging, I found I have Python installed twice, once in `/usr/local/bin` and once in `/usr/bin`.

```
timeroot@lepus-leaps:~$ /usr/bin/python3 --version
Python 3.8.2
timeroot@lepus-leaps:~$ /usr/local/bin/python3 --version
Python 3.8.3
```

Both of these directories are on my default PATH, and it's been running the `local` version, which I don't want. How do I get rid of it safely? I could just remove the file, but I'm worried that will leave a lot of junk floating around elsewhere, leading to more problems down the road. (Like for instance `pip3`, which also exists twice.)

As a second side-question, any clue how this could have happened?

Comment: I wonder of you manually installed python at some time (compiled it yourself).  /usr/bin/python3 may have been installed through your package manager and installed automatically.

Comment: @PhilipCouling ah, yes, you're right! I think I did that a number of months ago and totally forgot about it (until my PATH changed and I started getting problems.) That's exactly what happened. Unfortunately installing Python from source doesn't seem to have any built-in uninstaller. Getting ready to sink some time into this now...

Answer (score 1):

As Philip Couling correctly guessed, this was a result of installing Python from source a while ago. Unfortunately, the official python distribution has no uninstaller option. However, running `make -n install` showed the complete list of actions it would take on my machine, and I was able to then write the appropriate opposite commands. In case it helps anyone else, here are the commands I used:

```
rm -r /usr/local/lib/python3.8 #all install pip packages
rm /usr/local/lib/libpython3.8.a

rm -r /usr/local/include/python3.8 #all include packages

rm /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/python3.pc
rm /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/python3-embed.pc
rm /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/python-3.8.pc
rm /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/python-3.8-embed.pc
rm /usr/local/bin/easy_install-3.8
rm /usr/local/bin/idle3
rm /usr/local/bin/idle3.8
rm /usr/local/bin/ipython
rm /usr/local/bin/ipython3
rm /usr/local/bin/iptest
rm /usr/local/bin/iptest3
rm /usr/local/bin/2to3
rm /usr/local/bin/2to3-3.8
rm /usr/local/bin/f2py
rm /usr/local/bin/f2py3
rm /usr/local/bin/f2py3.8
rm /usr/local/bin/pip
rm /usr/local/bin/pip3
rm /usr/local/bin/pip3.8
rm /usr/local/bin/pydoc3
rm /usr/local/bin/pydoc3.8
rm /usr/local/bin/pygmentize
rm /usr/local/bin/python3
rm /usr/local/bin/python3.8
rm /usr/local/bin/python3-config
rm /usr/local/bin/python3.8-config
```